# Pass Object from performSelector

Tags: ios, objective-c, performselector

I have a method in another class and I call this method like this

```
[captureView performSelector:@selector(startRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

But now want to pass an object to this method, so I know I want to change it to this:

```
[captureView performSelector:@selector(startRecording) withObject:assest afterDelay:1.0];
```

But then if my method `startRecording` looks like this

```
- (bool) startRecording{
```

What do I change it to, in order to use the variable asset in this new method?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Suggestion - use `dispatch_after` to call the method directly instead of using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. Much easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, "... A selector that identifies the method to invoke. The method should not have a significant return value and should take a single argument of type id, or no arguments."

So your method can't return a BOOL, and it needs to look like this,

```
- (void) startRecording:(id) obj{
    ...
}
```

You also need to add a colon to your selector name in `performSelector:@selector(startRecording:)`